# recieved json automapping into input model

Tags: asp.net-core, knockout.js

I have following html form

```
<input type="hidden" name="JsonCustomers" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(customers)" />
<input type="hidden" name="JsonMaterials" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(materials)" />
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-sm btn-primary">Submit</button>
```

and input model class

```
public class SubmitViewModel
{
    public string JsonCustomers { get; set; }
    public string JsonMaterials { get; set; }
}
```

Controller action

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Submit(SubmitViewModel model)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

it is possible to automap Json into something like this ?

```
public class SubmitViewModel
    {
        public IEnumerable<InputCustomer> Customers { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<InputMaterial> Materials { get; set; }
    }
```

I would like to skip conversion step from the Json into collection and ideally use data annotations with ModelState.IsValid function. Any idea ?

**UPDATE**

**html**

```
<input type="hidden" name="JsonCustomers" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(customers)" />
<input type="hidden" name="JsonMaterials" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(materials)" />
<input type="hidden" name="Customers" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(customers)" />
<input type="hidden" name="Materials" data-bind="value: ko.toJSON(materials)" />
```

content of **JsonCustomers** after form submit

```
[{"isChecked":true,"name":"CompanyA","volume":"80","expectedDateOfOrder":"1.1.2018"},{"isChecked":true,"name":"CompanyB","volume":"100","expectedDateOfOrder":"2.2.2018"},{"isChecked":true,"name":"CompanyC","volume":"150","expectedDateOfOrder":"3.3.2018"}]
```

customer class

```
public class Customer
    {
        public bool? IsChecked { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Volume { get; set; }
        public string ExpectedDateOfOrder { get; set; }
    }
```

the issue is that `public IEnumerable<Customer> Customers` collection has **Count = 0**, i dont know why.

this is from FormCollection
[image]

Comment: It should work out of the box. What is your problem?

Comment: I have Count 0 in both collections :( tomorrow i will check again if all collection properties match to json

Comment: It does not work i dont know what else to do.

Comment: could you share your json along with Customer and Material models?

Comment: yes, i was already updating question.

Comment: it looks like part of your request, could you post the whole request? Otherwise I can't help you to build correct model

Comment: But it is whole json for this input name, in what format do you want whole http request ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176112/discussion-between-muflix-and-alex-riabov).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With help from @Alex Riabov and based on this discussion https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/5760

```
model.Customers = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IEnumerable<InputCustomer>>(model.JsonCustomers);
```

in the controller action did the trick.